# Why doesn't his php include mechanism work? I can't seem to find the issue

Tags: php, include

I have a website that was built by someone else about 10 years ago. Basically it has an index.php and the content inside changes dynamically based on what link the user clicks on.

It gets the url from this script:

```
<?php
//Aktuális url-------------------------------
function cururl() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

$oldal = isset($_GET["site"]) ? $_GET["site"] : 'fooldal';

switch ($oldal) {
    case "hirek":
        $lap = 'hirek.php';
        $title = "Hírek";
        break;
    case "az-alapitvanyrol":
        $lap = 'az-alapitvanyrol.php';
        $title = "Az alapítványról";
        break;
    // További esetek hozzáadása ...
    default:
        $lap = 'fooldal.php';
        $title = "Kis Virtuózok Alapítvány";
        break;
}
```

and then it includes the page:

```
<?php
        include($lap);
?>
```

The navigation looks like this:

```
<li><a href="hirek">Hírek</a></li>
```

If I click on the A href, it just redirects me to the `www.website.com/hirek` which returns with a 404. I tried to change the href to `/`, but it seems like it gets the info from the url, but then it also tries to simply open the `/hirek` page which does not point anywhere. Can any of you help me to fix this issue? I've ran out of ideas..

Comment: Are there rewrite rules in place? Seems like this would need to rewrite anything after `/` to `index.php?site=` and the value after the slash.

Comment: Did the original also rely on some rules in a `.htaccess` file, perhaps?